# ''You must install peer dependencies yourself.'' shows up when Importing Weather icon from cloning a GitHub link

Tags: css, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am trying to import weather icons by cloning a link from https://github.com/erikflowers/weather-icons. But looks like the installation of the css file is not successful. The following info was shown in the terminal:

```
npm WARN react-scripts@3.3.0 requires a peer of typescript@^3.2.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sass-loader@8.0.0 requires a peer of node-sass@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sass-loader@8.0.0 requires a peer of sass@^1.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sass-loader@8.0.0 requires a peer of fibers@>= 3.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Do I have to manually install something myself?

Answer (score -3):

Yes! You have to do:

```
npm i typescript@^3.2.1 node-sass@^4.0.0 sass@^1.3.0 fibers@>= 3.1.0 typescript@>=2.8.0
```

Happy coding